# What C function (or interface) is the pyperclip module in python based on?

Tags: python, c, module, pyperclip

Look, I'm wondering what C function the pyperclip library in python is based on. I couldn't find this information so I decided to ask here. And as I understand, these fundamental functions differ on different Operating Systems, so I’m interested in Ubuntu

Comment: Have you tried to read the [source](https://github.com/asweigart/pyperclip/tree/master)?

Comment: On Linux the clipboard is specified by [freedesktop.org](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/). You could search its site for specifications and other documentation. Or use a framework like Gtk or similar to help you.

Comment: @MichaelButscher, thank you very much, next time I’ll go straight to GitHub 

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I'm not a Linux or Ubuntu professional, but I'm wondering what C function (or functions) **pyperclip** on Linux is based on. I'm not interested in how the clipboard itself is formed. Anyway, thank you very much, dude!

Comment: There's no standard C function for this. It's dependent on the OS and window system, so the library has different code for Windows, MacOS, Linux.

Comment: @Barmar, Thanks for noticing. I asked a clumsy question, I needed to give an example with subprocess and execv(), because I just wanted to learn more about pyperclip. In short, as a result, I found information about xclip() and xsel().

Comment: How low level do you need to get? How high level? At the lowest level the common protocol seems to be the X11 ICCCM protocol (if I read the freedesktop.org texts correctly), which have a set of very low-level functions. Then there are libraries and frameworks on top of that. Some which might incorporate Wayland in addition to X11. I really recommend you find a library or framework to do all the low-level jobs, and then use it for your needs.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, Look, I personally still have enough to understand that pyperclip is based on `xclip()` and `xsel()`. I have a personal pet project that does routine work for me, but I don't know how it works in detail, so I decided to dive a little deeper. That is, I need this information not for some other project, but simply for erudition or something like that. But thank you very much for your work, that you found useful information for other people who will look for it

Comment: What *practical problem do you hope to solve* by obtaining this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's based on `xclip()` or `xsel()` that require X11 implementation

[xclip.c](https://github.com/astrand/xclip/blob/master/xclip.c) has its own functions:

- `*get_requestor`,
- `del_requestor`,
- `clean_requestors`,
- `doOptMain`,
- `doOptSel`,
- `doOptTarget`,
- `doIn`,
- `printSelBuf`,
- `doOut`

[xsel.c](https://github.com/kfish/xsel/blob/master/xsel.c) functions:

- `get_atom_name`
- `debug_property`
- `xs_malloc`
- `_xs_strdup`
- `_xs_strncpy`
- `get_xdg_cache_home`
- `block_exit_sigs`
- `unblock_exit_sigs`
- `alarm_handler`
- and other (about 49 more)

Linux Clipboard itself is based on [freedesktop.org](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/)

Repositories: [pyperclip](https://github.com/asweigart/pyperclip/tree/master), [xclip](https://github.com/astrand/xclip), [xsel](https://github.com/kfish/xsel) 
Found: [Michael Butscher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/987358/michael-butscher), [Some Programmer Dude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/some-programmer-dude), [Håkon Hægland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2173773/h%C3%A5kon-h%C3%A6gland)

Comment: *"..what C function the pyperclip library in python is based on..(Ubuntu)"*: C functions are given here: https://github.com/astrand/xclip/blob/master/xclip.c